# How to get the Vertex shader from program

Tags: javascript, webgl

Can I use the Webgl api to get the vertex shader (only) from a program (`WebGlProgram`)?
There is a `gl.getAttachedShaders()` which gives me an array of them. Is there a way to determine which is which?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [WebGL Specification; 5.13.9 Programs and Shaders](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0.0/#5.13.9)

> `any getShaderParameter(WebGLShader shader, GLenum pname)`
>
> Return the value for the passed `pname` given the passed shader. The type returned is the natural type for the requested `pname`, as given in the following table:
>
> ```
> SHADER_TYPE     unsigned long
> DELETE_STATUS   boolean
> COMPILE_STATUS  boolean
> ```

Use [`gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.SHADER_TYPE)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getShaderParameter), to determine if the shader object `shader`, which is returned by `gl.getAttachedShaders`, is a vertex or fragment shader. The possible return values are `gl.VERTEX_SHADER` and `gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER`.